# Self-referential foundations

Tags: foundations, philosophy

A standard way to approach formalization (judging from my experience) is to set up a kind of informal metatheory with few foundational concepts, such as the metalogical implication $\Rightarrow$, metalogical sets, functions,  $n$-tuples, structural induction, etc. All of these must be understood, by definition, in and of themselves, they are like a cornerstone of our proverbial Tower of Mathematics (or some other philosophically useful formal system).

This got me thinking: The only alternative to this ground-up approach that I can conceive of is a *circular*, *self-referential* foundation. One simple example of such a foundation in natural language that came to my mind was:

> This sentence is true.

I would like to know whether such an approach to the foundations of formal systems has ever been explored, and if so, does it have any mathematical and/or philosophical significance?

Comment: Self-referencing, or impredicativity, is exactly the thing that the study of  mathematical foundation arises to avoid.

Comment: @Trebor Could you elaborate? Why would a self-referential foundation be problematic?

Comment: @user10354138 This example doesn't seem problematic to me. Rule (1) is the statement $\text{I am right}$ and Rule (2) seems to be the statement $\neg\text{I am right} \to \text{I am right}$, which is equivalent to $\text{I am right}$, so we really have only one rule. I fail to see which philosophical issues could be raised against such a system, unless self-reference is taken to be problematic in and of itself. But why would it be?

Comment: Truth is not a syntactic property.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I don't see how self-reference would entail that truth is a syntactic property. I see no problem in creating an unambiguous syntax whose formulas would represent the semantic self-referential statements in some (or all) models.

Comment: You can see [Constructive type theory](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/type-theory-intuitionistic/)

Comment: But also [Hilbert's original approach](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/hilbert-program/#1.1) to the foundational issue was to develop "partly simultaneously logic and arithmetic" exactly in order to avoid "circularity". See [Hilbert (1904)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/27899603?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents).